# Using 'foreach' values to plugin to database query then echo back into the table

Tags: php, database, mysqli, foreach, html-table

After much tweaking I've finally got my table looking half decent:

```
<table id="Productslist" class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Part </th>
        <th> Brand </th>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Price </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
            $part = find_part();    
            foreach($parts_list as $col => $value) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$col.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td>
            <td>'.$part['Name'].'</td></tr>';
                    }

        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td> Total </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The foreach loop works great! as it finds the column name and value within that column and inserts it into their own rows. Fantastic! Now I really want to use the `$col` and `$value` in a database query but when I try it either in the function or by global retrieval it doesn't work.... any insight?

```
   function find_part() {
     global $db;
     global $col;
     global $value;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM " .$col. "";
     $sql .= "WHERE ID='" . $value ."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     $part = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     return $part;  }
```

or

```
    function find_part($col, $value) {
     global $db;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM " .$col. "";
     $sql .= "WHERE ID='" . $value ."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     $part = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     return $part;  }
```

Both times the error_log says that its and undefined index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the values as a parameters in your function. Use following code.

```
<?php 
            foreach($parts_list as $col => $value) {
             $part = find_part($col, $value);    
             echo '<tr><td>'.$col.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td>
             <td>'.$part['Name'].'</td></tr>';
            }

?>
```

Use this with below code.

```
function find_part($col, $value) {
     global $db;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM " .$col. "";
     $sql .= "WHERE ID='" . $value ."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     $part = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     return $part;  
}
```

You will be able to get $col and $value in this function.

### Update

To skip an iteration in foreach loop

```
if($col == 'ID'){
continue; //it will skip the iteration and start next one.
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!!!! @SmitR Just need to make it work with every database query now because i don't have 'Name' in each database, yet another head scratcher ....

Comment: Good Luck. If you have any issue you can ask here. @Survivor28

Comment: is there a way for the Foreach function to ignore a few results (not in order) with an IF statement? i.e. IF($col = 'ID' echo "") if that makes sense?

Comment: You my friend, are a god! Thank you! @SmitR

Comment: Welcome, Glad I could help. :) @Survivor28